# How to send a daily message with a telegram chat-bot without knowing the chat_id?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, telegram-bot

The bot works well when has to reply to a message because it retrieves the chat_id from it and then sends something back, however it doesn't work for sending a daily message to all the active chats because it's not replying to any message.

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

TOKEN = '<<TOKEN>>'

# Function to send the daily message
def send_daily_message(app):
    return app.bot.send_message(text='Good morning')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()

    # Commands
    async def start_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Bot running")

    # Commands
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))

    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(send_daily_message(app), 'cron', hour=14, minute=52)
    scheduler.start()

    # Start the bot
    print('Starting the bot...')
    app.run_polling(poll_interval=3)
```

The code returns:
`TypeError: ExtBot.send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chat_id'`
because the bot doesn't know to what id has to send the message.
How can I fix the problem?